# Flutterwave inline api success response

Tags: flutterwave

Picture 1
[image: Response code 1]

Picture 2
[image: Response code 2]

The above are two different response from flutterwave inline api. The first picture is card payment response while the second is bank transfer response.

Actually i'm confused which to rely on whether the status or the charge_response_code. Though both have the same "charge_response_code":"00" but different "status":(successful, completed),
My question is does "00" always mean that the payment was successful? Can i rely on it?

Answer (score 0):

The outer status an indicator the your request was successfully received and processed.

The inner **charge_response_code** is the REAL status of the transaction.